# Moving 'category-view' div out of 'column-main'

Tags: magento2.3.3, sidebar, category-view

Using Magento 2.3.2.

I want to move the `category-view` div out of the `column-main` div whilst still keeping it under the `columns` div. So it is a sub-div of `columns` (like `column-main`) rather than a sub-div of `column-main` itself.

I essentially need the sidebar, category details, and product grid as three separate divs that I can order.

At the moment `column-main` is one entity that I can either place the sidebar before or after in mobile breakpoints.

That is a really convoluted way of saying:
I want to be able to place the sidebar (filter) in-between the category details and the product grid in mobile breakpoints.

Any help would be gratefully received.
Thank you.